# Can sports newspaper clippings carry similiar value as sports cards?

Tags: statistics

I know sports cards can carry much value or little value depending on many variables (the player, year, stats, condition of card, etc). But can sports clippings from newspaper carry value other than nostalgia?

Comment: Your question isn't so clear, can you give an example?

Comment: A newspaper that has a significant event on it. For example, the '69 or '86 Mets winning the World Series or when the men's hockey team beat Russia in the Olympics.

Comment: Is your question about comparing news clippings to sports cards? Or whether their worth is or isn't due to nostalgia? Or is it just "can sports clippings carry value", regardless of the comparison to sports cards.

Comment: Great question. I think it's more in regards to the latter half of your question. Whether they can carry value regardless of their comparison to sports cards.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how one could judge whether or not the monetary value people attach to these items is due to something "other than nostalgia", but yes, sports clippings can carry value. Here are [some examples on ebay](http://www.ebay.com/sch/Historical-Memorabilia-/13877/i.html?_ipg=50&_sadis=200&LH_SALE_CURRENCY=0&_from=R40&_samihi=&_samilow=&_fpos=&_udhi=&_oexkw=&_udlo=&_adv=1&_sop=12&_okw=&_dmd=1&_fsct=&_nkw=newspaper%20baseball&rt=nc). The monetary value could be because the buyers believe that *other* people value them for nostalgic reasons, and they're hoping to sell these items for more than they buy them for. I guess you could call that speculative value, but still possibly tied to nostalgia in the end. I think the question of what gives things value is more an economics question, rather than a sports question, though.